# Ajax’s Onreadystatechange Return Uncaught Typeerror

Tags: javascript, ajax, ajaxform

Am a newbie to ajax and am trying create a simple ajax webpage but I run into this problem

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onreadystatechange' of
>   undefined at window.onload (test.js:4)

And this is the test.js page code I created

```
window.onload = function(){
'use strict';
var ajax = getXMLHttpRequestObject();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(ajax.readyState == 4){
if((ajax.status >= 200 && ajax.status < 300) || (ajax.status == 304)){
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
}else{
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Error ' + ajax.statusText;
}
}
};
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
ajax.open('GET', 'resources/test.txt', true);
ajax.send(null);
};
}
function getXMLHttpRequestObject(){
var ajax = null;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else if(window.ActiveXObject){
ajax = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
} 
}
```

while this is the html page called test.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <title>Ajax test</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div><button type="button" id="btn">Run the test</button><br>
             <p id="output"></p>
         </div>
         <script src ="js/test.js"></script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Meanwhile, am trying to run it on XAMPP

Comment: `getXMLHttpRequestObject` returns nothing, which means it returns `undefined`. The `ajax` variable inside that function is not the same as the one outside.

Comment: You mean I should put the var ajax outside the 2 functions

Comment: No, return the object you want to use from the function. You're calling it like this `var ajax = getXMLHttpRequestObject();`, which means it is expecting to return some value. Therefore, you need to add `return` statements to the function that return the desired object.

Comment: ...for example, instead of `ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();` do this instead: `return new XMLHttpRequest();`

Comment: Thanks @ Crazy Train. Have been able to fix it

Comment: Yep, that'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

I just returned the variable ajax at the end of both functions.

>

```
 window.onload = function(){
>          'use strict';
>          var ajax = getXMLHttpRequestObject();
>          ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
>              if(ajax.readyState == 4){
>                  if((ajax.status >= 200 && ajax.status < 300) || (ajax.status == 304)){
>                      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
>                  }else{
>                      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Error ' + ajax.statusText;
>                  }
>              }
>          };
>              document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
>                  ajax.open('GET', 'resources/test.txt', true);
>                  ajax.send(null);
>              };
>              **return ajax;**
>      }
>      function getXMLHttpRequestObject(){
>          var ajax = null;
>          if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
>              ajax =  new XMLHttpRequest();
>          }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
>              ajax = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
>          }    
>          **return ajax**
>      }
```